# SQLite and Entity Framework

Tags: .net, sqlite, frameworks, entity, provider

I'm trying to use SQLITE database with latest Entity Framework. I've installed SQLite provider x86 for .NET Framework 4.0 from here: http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki.

I succesfully added SQLITE as new data source by using server explorer in Visual Studio 2012. Then, I added new ADO.NET Entity Model and tried to add tables from my simple sqlite database. For some reason these tables can't be added and error log says following:

> > The data type 'longchar' is currently not supported for the target .NET Framework version; >>the column 'Name' in table 'main.Person' was excluded.

I dont understand why it's trying to convert SQLite TEXT type to longchar and fails. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: the type of the field in the SQLite database is longchar? why don't use varchar or nvarchar instead of long char?

Comment: SQLite is practically typeless because types are handled as strings. It's providers job to determinite what type it should use. For some reason in my case the provider wants to handle my TEXT type as longchar and that's the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I was just getting this issue today after setting up my development environment for a project that uses SQLLITE and ADO at work and the fix was simple.  Version 1.0.85.0 is broken and version 1.0.84.0 works.

32 BIT:
http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.84.0/sqlite-netFx40-setup-bundle-x86-2010-1.0.84.0.exe

64 BIT:
http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.84.0/sqlite-netFx40-setup-bundle-x86-2010-1.0.84.0.exe

Uninstall make sure to delete the program files for each install and also when you re-install tell the installer to rebuild your GAC.  Should work that was the only difference between my and my boses build machine, that website needs to list previous revisions better.

Comment: If I'm right, that version of SQLite can be used only with Visual Studio 2010. I'm using 2012 so this will not help me. Thanks anyways.

Comment: You can get the 1.0.84.0 version for Visual Studio 2012 at http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.84.0/sqlite-netFx45-setup-bundle-x86-2012-1.0.84.0.exe

Comment: As odd as it seems, I was also having issues with Sqlite on VS 2012 after the project was started with VS 2010 and installing Version 1.0.85.0. I followed the instructions from user2333398 and @Chris-Woodruff and installed Version 1.0.84.0 and **voila** everything magically stared working! Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 0):

Alter your SQLite tables so that any TEXT fields are NVARCHAR(max) instead.  .Net should map them correctly then.